# Get single hash from array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes:

`[<name: bob, age: 25, orders: 3>, <name: george, age: 21, orders: 2>, <name: sandy, age: 23, orders: 5>, <name: sandy, age: 21, orders: 4>]`

I'd like a function that picks out a single hash based on two entries.  Ie I put in name="sandy" age=21.  It would come back with a simple hash <name: sandy, age:21, orders: 4>

I tried `Array.select {|e| e["name"] == "sandy" and e["age"] == 21}`
for some reason I get back the whole array.

In the above I was trying to isolate the offending code.  I still seem to be having issues, so full code below. I've done a lot of back and forth with debugging.  Some of this code might still be offensive...

```
    @budgets = Budget.all
    @budgetArray = @budgets.to_a
    @actuals = GeneralLedger.select("account_id, entryDate, sum(amount), CASE WHEN MONTH(entryDate) >= 4 THEN concat(YEAR(entryDate), '') ELSE concat(YEAR(entryDate)-1, '') END as fiscalY").group('account_id, fiscalY').order('account_id').to_a
    @currentYear = 2021
    @numGLYears=2
    #@numGLYears = GeneralLedger.select('count(distinct CASE WHEN MONTH(entryDate) >= 4 THEN concat(YEAR(entryDate), '') ELSE concat(YEAR(entryDate)-1, '') END) as fiscalY FROM general_ledgers').to_s.to_i
    @budgetTable = Array.new
    budgetRow = Array.new
    @budgetArray.each do |b|
        budgetRow.clear
        i=@numGLYears
        #budgetRow.push b.account_id
        while i >= 1
            budgetRow.push getBudget(@budgetArray, @currentYear-i, b.account_id)
            budgetRow.push getActuals(@actuals, @currentYear-i, b.account_id)
            i=i-1
        end
        @budgetTable.push budgetRow
    end
  end

  def getBudget(myArray, year, account)
    rtn = myArray.select{ |e| (e["year"] == year.to_s) and (e["account_id"] == account.to_s)}
    if rtn.nil?
        return '-'
    else
        return rtn
    end
    #get budget if there else '-'
  end
  
  def getActuals(myArray, year, account)
    rtn = myArray.find{ |e| e["year"] == year.to_s and e["account_id"] == account.to_s}
    if rtn.nil?
        return '********************' + year.to_s + account.to_s
    else
        return rtn
    end
  end
```

Comment: 1) Your code works against an input of hashes. Just call `.first` after the selector. 2) Is the input an array of hashes or an array of objects? That syntax suggests the latter. 3) is `Array` a class or the variable assignment of array? Either way it's confusing 4) Is this a rails question?

Comment: I edited the question above.  Yes this is originally coming out of ruby.  Perhaps I am getting an array of objects rather than an array of hashes, and that is what is causing some of the headaches?  As a side note, it is spitting out the final object/hash over and over rather than looping through as I thought it would.

Comment: There's a number of other issues in that code.  But they are unrelated to the original question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select` returns an array with all the elements that fulfill the condition.  Try `find` which will return the first *single* item that matches your conditions.

Also make sure your hash has the keys as strings and not symbols, otherwise you won't match any of your conditions.  There is a difference between `e[:name]` and `e["name"]`.

https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/select

https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/find